# How to count a property in a location and display all the property lists

Tags: sql

The query below returns the count with one property list but I need all the property lists in that count.

```sql
    SELECT locations.name, COUNT(properties.locationId) AS count, properties.*
      FROM locations
      JOIN properties ON locations.id = properties.locationId
      GROUP BY properties.locationId
```

How can I get both the count and the complete results?

Comment: if mysql, you can use "group_concat" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain all the properties of a location and repeatd on each row  the count of all properties this way

```
SELECT location.name, properties.*, t.count 
FROM locations  JOIN properties ON locations.id = properties.locationId
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT locations.id,locations.name,  COUNT(properties.locationId) as count
  FROM locations  JOIN properties ON locations.id = properties.locationId
  GROUP BY properties.locationId 

  ) t  on t.id = locations.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use window functions:

```
SELECT l.name, p.*, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY l.id) as cnt
FROM locations l JOIN
     properties p
     ON l.id = p.locationId;
```

Not only is the query shorted (and less prone to error than a version using `JOIN`/`GROUP BY`, but it should also have better performance.